# definir um polinômio de qualquer grau em Python

Tags: python, matemática

Trabalho com cálculo numérico, meu objetivo é fazer o uso de um "*least squares*". Eu to definindo uma função no Python da seguinte forma:

```
def F(P,x):
    return P[0] + P[1]*x + P[2]*x**2 + P[3]*x**3
```

Depois irei definir esse coeficientes P[0], P[1],...

Esse exemplo é fácil, porque o polinômio é de grau 3, mas pretendo fazer um polinômio de grau maior que 10. Então eu queria facilitar a definição desse polinômio. Digamos que antes eu defino grau = 3, grau = 4 ou qualquer valor e tornar prático a definição de um polinômio de grau qualquer no Python, isto é, eu escolho o grau, digamos 3 e e define me retornando da seguinte forma:

```
def F(P,x):
    return P[0] + P[1]*x + P[2]*x^2 + P[3]*x^3
```

Se eu escolho 4, me retornar da seguinte forma:

```
def F(P,x):
    return P[0] + P[1]*x + P[2]*x^2 + P[3]*x^3 + P[4]**x^4
```

Comment: Wilson - tente ser mais claro quanto ao que você realmente quer fazer em Python. O que você quer? Uma função para a qual você passe "4" e te devolva uma string com o polinômio? Ou que uma que você passe os coeficientes, e ela te devolva um objeto que possa ser chamado como uma função, (e aí calcula o polinômio) , e ainda com uma representação bonitinha?
Ou quer um objeto que possa manter o polinômio em sua forma simbólica, de forma que possa ser somado, multiplicado, etc... com outros polinômios antes de qualquer cálculo numérico? Tudo isso é possível em Python, mas não temos como adivinhar.

Comment: (A propósito: como a pergunta foi fechada, é mais fácil você refazer uma nova pergunta do que editar essa e esperar que seja reaberta)

Comment: @jsbueno Se ele tiver muitas perguntas fechadas o sistema pode acionar um limitador de tempo restringindo novos posts. Idealmente ele deve clicar em [edit], elaborar a pergunta aqui mesmo deixando clara a dúvida e aguardar possível abertura (conforme instrução no quadro amarelo acima). Imagine se ele refaz a pergunta e ainda faltam detalhes importantes e é fechada, vai fazer uma terceira depois?

Comment: pessoal, obrigado, eu editei novamente, espero ter sido mais claro.

Comment: `P` será uma lista com os coeficientes?

Comment: Será uma lista que irei encontrar os melhores valores usando um "least squares"

Comment: Votei para reabrir a pergunta. Acredito que você consiga fazer algo assim: https://repl.it/@acwoss/FondDarlingScreenscraper

Comment: Deu certo @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agora ficou simples - você só quer realmente uma função em Python que faça o cálculo numérico do polinômio, definido pelos coefientes em P.

Então é só você fazer um `for` percorrendo os coeficientes, e usando o `enmerate` para ter o expoente de X associado a cada coeficiciente.  O `enumerate` funciona assim: para cada elemento de uma sequência, ele devolve uma outra sequência de dois elementos em que o primeiro é o índice e o segundo é o próprio elemento.

Então calculamos cada parcela do polinômio e somamos todas - fazendo "por extenso":

```
def F(P, x):
    result = 0
    for exponent, coeficient in enumerate(P):
        result += coeficient * x ** exponent
    return result
```

Funciona se o P for uma lista ou qualquer outra sequência, já que o `for` em Python sempre percorre uma sequência.

Há uma sintaxe mais avançada também que permite o uso do for como uma expressão "inline", e não como comando em uma linha separada. Esse modelo cria um "generator expression" que pode ser passado diretamente para a função built-in `sum`:

```
def F(P, x):
    return sum(c * x ** e for (e, c) in enumerate(P))
```

E por fim, mas não menos importante, você pode ter uma classe polinômio - e com o tempo ir agregando funcionalidades a ela - se a classe receber uma lista de coeficientes em seu `__init__`, pode ter um método `__call__` que permite que seu polinômio calcule o seu valor para um dado "x" - e um `__repr__` que tenha uma representação legal do polinômio:

```
class Poli:
    def __init__(self, coeficients):
         self.coeficients = coeficients
    @property
    def degree(self):
         return len(coeficients) - 1
    def __call__(self, x):
         return sum(c * x ** e for (e, c) in enumerate(self.coeficients))
    def __repr__(self):
         return f"P({})".format(" + ".join(f"{c} * x ** {e}" for e, c in enumerate(self.coeficients))
```

Comment: @jsnueno eu peguei o segundo modo, achei mais tranquilo de se trabalhar, visto que sou aprendiz na linguagem. Valeu!